# Implied probabilities into odds

Tags: probability

I am investigating the probability of one player scoring more points than another player in a game and have come across a problem when trying to compare more than 2 players.

My problem is as follows: 
Given:
P(Player A scores more than Player B)=0.530
P(Player B scores more than Player A)=0.470
P(Player A scores more than Player C)=0.567
P(Player C scores more than Player A)=0.433
P(Player B scores more than Player C)=0.537
P(Player C scores more than Player B)=0.463

How can this information be represented as odds that one player outscores both of the other players? i.e. Player A scores more than both B and C?

Thank you for your help!